# How to list hosts on the current network without knowing the subnet in advance?

Tags: networking, nmap

The following 2 questions have been useful for finding hosts on a target network:

- [Display list of computers on a LAN in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/311019)
- [How to find live hosts on my network?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36198/35859)

However, answers in both questions assume I know the network address and mask (subnet, I guess?) in advance (192.168.0.0/24, 172.18.72.0/24, etc).

How can I find hosts on any/all connected networks without specifying the subnet in advance?
I know I can list the network devices using `ip address show` (Arch Linux), `ifconfig` (*nix, OS X), or `ipconfig` (Windows) depending on the operating system.

Furthermore, Is there a reliable way to do it across operating systems? From Linux to OS X to Windows?

Comment: You listed all the tools you need already. ifconfig/ipconfig would be the way to get the IP/subnet mask across all networks, and you can filter it down with batch/bash, but you'd likely need something like python or perl to manage the return strings and run them through nmap. The basic answer is to use a scripting language.

Comment: Drat, I was hoping to take the easy way out and find an already finished implementation. I also didn't think it was normal for parsing ifconfig/ipconfig input. I was hoping to drive something like `netsh` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-platform solution that will work on any system that Nmap works on, use Nmap's `--iflist` argument:

```
./nmap --iflist

Starting Nmap 6.41SVN ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-12-18 04:55 UTC
************************INTERFACES************************
DEV     (SHORT)   IP/MASK                TYPE     UP   MTU   MAC
eth0    (eth0)    192.0.2.5/24           ethernet up   1500  F2:3C:DE:AD:BE:B8
eth0    (eth0)    2001:db8::dead:beef/64 ethernet up   1500  F2:3C:91:AE:FC:B8
eth0    (eth0)    fe80::dead:beef/64     ethernet up   1500  F2:3C:91:AE:FC:B8
lo      (lo)      127.0.0.1/8            loopback up   65536
lo      (lo)      ::1/128                loopback up   65536

**************************ROUTES**************************
DST/MASK                DEV  METRIC GATEWAY
192.0.2.0/24            eth0 0
0.0.0.0/0               eth0 100    192.0.2.1
::1/128                 lo   0
2001:db8::dead:beef/128 lo   0
fe80::dead:beef/128     lo   0
2001:db8::/64           eth0 256
fe80::/64               eth0 256
ff00::/8                eth0 256
::/0                    eth0 1024   fe80::1
```

At this point, it becomes a matter of parsing out the info you want. Probably you are looking for something under `ROUTES`, but be sure you don't scan localhost!

Comment: `--iflist` is cool, I didn't notice that option.